# Troubleshoot libvirt-managed qemu x86-64 UEFI guest

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, uefi

I have a libvirt/qemu/x64 UEFI guest running Windows 10. The problem is that it starts successfully every other time.

1. When I issue a guest start commmand (any libvirt method) 1st time, the guest starts executing UEFI and is then shut down before trying to boot from storage. I verified by setting it to boot W10 install media first.
2. When I start second time, it boots normally.

   A good start/shutdown looks like this: [good qemu start](https://pastebin.com/TMn1kf8P)
   A bad start looks like this: [bad qemu start](https://pastebin.com/wFRzsvez)

I'm looking for advice to add more logging to see the nature of my problem

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, there's no difference in the 2 sets of command line args shown in those two pastebins. The messages after the CLI args are just debug messages from SPICE, so shouldn't affect whether it boots successfully or not. So there's no really enough info to diagnose the problem described. Might be better to report the problem to your OS distro vendor's bug tracker to get more help. It could be a problem with QEMU 2.10.0 release, so if you have the option then try either 2.9.0 or 2.10.1 and see if it makes any difference to success.